# Does "A is coupled to B (so as) not to rotate relative to B" make sense?

Tags: subordinate-clauses, to-infinitive, terminology

> A is coupled to B so that they can rotate together.

I am trying to rewrite the above sentence I created such that the rewritten one has the same meaning but is expressed in opposite way.  My examples are as follows:

> 1. A is coupled to B (so as) not to rotate relative to B.
> 2. A is coupled to B in a manner that prohibits/prevents A from rotating relative to B.
> 3. A is coupled to B in a manner that prohibits/prevents/does not allow relative rotation between A and B.

After I googled, I know that native speakers prefer the second and third sentences whereas non-native speakers prefer the first sentense.

I prefer the first one because it is shortest and simplest. The sentence is somewhat technical, but I would like to know only whether the first one is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A with "so as" is grammatically correct. You can even find it with some examples in [a dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/so-as).

However, it does sound odd and it may require more mental effort from your readers to understand.

A similar but more common way of expressing this idea would be

> A is coupled to B such that it cannot rotate relative to B.